# How do I denote that arguments are related?

Tags: gnu-parallel

I have the following arguments `chr1 chr2 chr3`, `+ -` and `2 3`.

For every `chr` I want to have `+` and `2` once and `-` and `3` once, like this:

```
parallel --whatflags-to-use?? echo {} {} {} ::: + - ::: 2 3 ::: chr1 chr2 chr3
+ 2 chr1
+ 2 chr2
+ 2 chr3
- 3 chr1
- 3 chr2
- 3 chr3
```

The closest I have gotten is this:

```
parallel --xapply echo {} {} {} ::: + - ::: 2 3 ::: chr1 chr2 chr3
+ 2 chr1
+ 2 chr3
- 3 chr2
```

How do I do this? Could not see how in the brilliant tutorial, so perhaps it is not possible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
parallel echo {} ::: '+ 2' '- 3' ::: chr1 chr2 chr3
```

If you need the arguments split, it is a bit harder: You want one argument to depend on another:

```
parallel echo strand='{=1 $_=$_==2?"+":"-"=}' read={1} chrom={2} ::: 2 3 ::: chr1 chr2 chr3
```

Alternatively:

```
parallel --xapply echo str={1} read={2} chrom={3}  ::: + - ::: 2 3 ::: chr{1,1,2,2,3,3}
parallel --colsep ' ' echo str={1} read={2} chrom={3}  ::: '+ 2' '- 3' ::: chr{1..3}
```

Comment: From 20160422 you will be able to do: parallel echo str={1} read={2} chrom={3}  ::: + - :::+ 2 3 ::: chr{1,2,3}

Answer (score 0):

```
parallel --xapply echo {} {} {} ::: + - + - + - ::: 2 3 2 3 2 3 ::: chr1 chr2 chr3
+ 2 chr1
- 3 chr1
+ 2 chr3
- 3 chr2
+ 2 chr2
- 3 chr3
```

Is one way to solve it, but it is rather stupid, since I have 25 chromosomes (chr) so I would have to write `+ -` and `2 3` 25 times each.